# Why does \AddToHook{enddocument} create an extra page with the standalone class?

Tags: standalone, lthooks

As shown in the following MWE, `\AddToHook{enddocument}` creates an extra page with the `standalone` class (with `varwidth` option), compared to the `article` class. Why, and is there a workaround?

```
% \documentclass[varwidth=15cm]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}

\AddToHook{enddocument}{That's all folks!}

\begin{document}
Once upon a time, ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: standalone redefines \enddocument to prepend its code to finish the page. Your code is then too late.

Comment: OK. `\AddToHook{cmd/sa@cls@beforeenddocument/before}{That's all folks!}` seems to do the trick, hoping there isn't any side effect.